# Calendar chart with amCharts

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to make a calendar chart like [Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar) one with amCharts ?
It represent user activity according to hour of day.

I tried to do it with amXYChart but it does not look good :[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you may not be able to make a chart exactly like the Google calendar one with its outlines around each month, I think you can get fairly close to the same aesthetic.

Have a review of the amCharts heatmap example:

- http://www.amcharts.com/tips/heat-map-chart/

The colors in the original amcharts example are a bit strong, so here is the same version using a colorbrewer palette:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will use that to understand what seems no good in my graph